# How to Catch Error When Data is not Sent on Angularfire when adding data to firebase?

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

Im using angularfire to save data into my firebase. Here is a quick code.

```
$scope.users.$add({ 
            Name:$scope.username,
            Age:$scope.newage,
            Contact: $scope.newcontact,
          });

 alert('Saved to firebase');
```

I am successful in sending these data to my firebase however how can I catch an error if these data are not saved successfully? Any ideas?

**EDIT**

So after implementing then() function.

```
$scope.users.$add({   
        Name:'Frank',
        Age:'20',
        Contact: $scope.newcontact,
      }).then(function(ref) {
 alert('Saved.');
 }).catch(function(error) {
 console.error(error); //or
 console.log(error);
 alert('Not Saved.');
 });
```

When connected to the internet. The then() function is fine. It waits for those data to be saved in firebase before showing the alert.
What I want is for it to tell me that data is not saved. catch error function is not firing when i am turning off my internet connection and submitting those data.

Comment: how are you declaring `$scope.users`?

Comment: var ref = firebase.database().ref('SOMETHING').child('SOMETHING');

Comment: And then  $scope.users= $firebaseArray(ref);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `$add()` it returns a promise. To detect when the data was saved, implement `then()`. To detect when saving failed, implement `catch()`:

```
var list = $firebaseArray(ref);
list.$add({ foo: "bar" }).then(function(ref) {
  var id = ref.key;
  console.log("added record with id " + id);
  list.$indexFor(id); // returns location in the array
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.error(error);
});
```

See the [documentation for `add()`](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md#addnewdata).

### Update

To detect when the data cannot be saved due to not having a network connection is a very different problem when it comes to the Firebase Database. Not being able to save in this case is not an error, but merely a temporary condition. This condition doesn't apply just to this `set()` operation, but to all read/write operation. For this reason, you should handle it more globally, by [detecting connection state](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state):

```
var connectedRef = firebase.database().ref(".info/connected");

connectedRef.on("value", function(snap) {
  if (snap.val() === true) {
    alert("connected");
  } else {
    alert("not connected");
  }
});
```

By listening to `.info/connected` your code can know that the user is not connected to the Firebase Database and handle it according to your app's needs.

Comment: Well said. One thing is I'm having a problem with the catch error function is not firing as i am expecting.

Comment: Can you set up a **minimal** jsfiddle/jsbin that reproduces the problem? That'll make it much easier/faster to help.

Comment: tried using console.log(error) but i think it is not firing as what i have observed in the logs. With the then() function i think it is firing because it waits for the data to be sent before showing logs in the console but when I Tried turning off my internet connection, and when i send the data, there was no error found. what i want is for it to tell me that it was not sent. thanks in advance

Comment: still new to this and i dont know how to make those jsfiddle or jsbin. For the main time I have updated and edited my question.

Comment: Ah, I now see. Your question is different from what I originally understood: you don't want to detect when failing saves, you want to detect when there is no connection. That is *very* different for Firebase. I added some information to my answer.

Comment: Sorry for misleading you. Thank you :)